# visual studio 2012 designer view error

Tags: visual-studio-2012

My Solution work properly but after some change in project properties, now when I try to open forms of project, below error occurred:

Cannot find type System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplayAttribute in module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary

Call Stack:

at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
 at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError)
 at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyModule.ResolveTypeRef(ITypeReference typeReference)
 at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyTypeReference.GetResolvedTypeWorker()
 at Microsoft.MetadataReader.TypeProxy.GetResolvedType()
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUtil.GetRuntimeType(Type type)

.
.

There are no problem when run program or open other project forms.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What have you changed? Does it work if you go back to the previous version?

Comment: Assembly name, Root namespace and product name. No, it doesn't work even back previous names. Thanks

Comment: Did you try to restart VS after cleaning the solution? Then rebuild again? I sometimes experience the same glitches with the designer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved by Microsoft forum.

[Thread Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c01eba6b-a333-4b82-97ab-49156d8dc9ec/visual-studio-2012-designer-view-error)

Thanks all